# Groovy mock method in unit test ignoring the order of elements in a List

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, mocking

I want to set expectation for a mocked class method in my unit test. The method I want to mock takes a List of elements as input params. How do I set expectations so that the order of elements in the list is ignored while calling the mock?

For eg:

mockClass method signature

```
String foo(List<String> list)
```

I am setting expectation this way currently

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add{"a"}
list.add{"b"}
list.add{"c"}
and:
    mockClass.foo(list) >> "test"
```

This test is failing intermittently because the order of elements in the list differs in when the method is called during testing.

Comment: The calls to `list.add` should use '(' and ')' not braces (ie '{' and '}'). There's no way that code works as you expect with those curly braces.

Comment: The ordering of the list will always be honored from the looks of the code you posted.  The list will always be `["a", "b","c"]`.  So if it's failing it's not because the order is changing.  You'll need to be more specific as to why you think the order has any bearing on the failure.  Mocked methods don't interpret arguments beyond simple comparison.  Depending on how you mocked your method that might have an impact, but failure would be constant.  It wouldn't be intermittent.

Answer (score 0):

The argThat closure can be used to define a custom argument matcher that ignores the order of elements in the list.

Eg:

```
when:
        def result = mockClass.foo(argThat { it.sort() == ["a", "b", "c"].sort() })



then:
   //somecode

where:
    argThat = { Closure<Boolean> closure ->
        { closure(it) } as org.hamcrest.Matcher
    }
```